# MSSQL and KAFKA integration

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to kafka. I am trying to import data from MSSQL to Hive using kafka (real-time data) with incremental and updated data. I saw github's confluent platform for mysql to hdfs data transfer, but I didn't find for MSSQL. Anybody is working on this please suggest me how to integrate MSSQL and kafka?

Comment: As Gwen mentioned, Striim will allow you to stream real-time incremental changes from MSSQL to Kafka. Let me know if you need help getting started with it:

http://www.striim.com/download-striim-for-confluent/

Answer (score 1):

I've heard Striim offers MSSQL change capture support.
Another option is to use the JDBC source connector (also on Confluent's github)

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have a doubt.what are the requirements for confluent jdbc connector.zookeeper and kafka already need to installed or in platform itself will come.Any body is using this now.Any guidelines for how to start kafka-server and how to store data into kafka broker.

Comment: which one is better.In my cluster we already installed zookeeper and kafka.